# Can't find COM ports in Device Manager (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, serial-port, device-manager

I have tried "Show hidden devices" but it didn't work

I'm using an Intel Compute Stick with Windows 10 installed. I have a USB serial converter hooked up. I'm trying to communicate with PuTTY, but can't find which COM port to use. The Device Manager doesn't list COM ports. All advice I've seen so far has said to Show hidden devices. This hasn't worked.

The serial converter does show up under USB controllers as "USB Serial Converter." Its location is listed as Port_#0003.Hub_#0001. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the device and latest drivers, but that didn't change anything. It seems to be using the FTDI driver v2.12.26.0.

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with the serial converter or the computer.

Comment: What brand is the serial converter?

Comment: It's an Adafruit FT232H Breakout - General Purpose USB to GPIO+SPI+I2C

https://www.adafruit.com/product/2264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to open the serial converter's properties in the device manager and choose VCP (virtual com port). This made COM appear.